# duplicate key value INSERT ON CONFLICT UPDATE

Tags: postgresql, upsert

With this table definition:

```
create table t1
(
    id uuid not null primary key,
    "u1" integer not null references u,
    "p1" integer not null references p,
    "c1" text,
    unique ("u1", "p1")
);

create unique index "t1_p1_unique" on t1 ("p1");
```

And this query:

```
INSERT INTO "t1" ("id","p1","u1","c1")
VALUES ('some-uuid',1,2,'3')
ON CONFLICT ("p1")
DO UPDATE SET "p1"=EXCLUDED."p1","u1"=EXCLUDED."u1","c1"=EXCLUDED."c1"
RETURNING "id","p1","u1","c1";
```

When many queries runs (with same p1 and u1 values), this error appear: `duplicate key value violates unique constraint t1_u1_p1_key`

Since `p1` has unique constraint, and request is `ON CONFLICT ("p1")` how is it possible to create a duplicate key on index `unique ("u1", "p1")`? The conflict should be detected, and the second query should update.

Comment: After `create unique index "t1_p1_unique" on t1 ("p1");` your `unique ("u1", "p1")` become obviously excess and should be removed.

Comment: thanks akina. Should I consider this structure issue the source of the problem?

Comment: I doubt. Your issue looks like duplicate issue on secondary constraint (this is similar to double fault). This can be a specificity of this situation, a specificity of secondary unique constraint violation handling algorithm in Postgres. Also this can be an effect of your query (which seems to be strange to me).. What is the reason to renew a column value when old and new values are the same? And what is the reason to generate new `id` and store all old values when the conflict occures?

Comment: Sorry in the query, "c1" differs for each request instance.
About generating new `id`, where is this done? Only `insert` define an `id` as far I see.
About storing all old values, I guess this is ORM-generated and our app do not care so...